# viewmodelscope.launch Obtener valor de retorno

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-corrutinas

quiero obtener el Id insertado para mostrar un mensaje e ir a un fragmento.
Estoy usando Fragment - ViewModel - Corroutines.
Adjunto código.

VIEWMODEL

```
val _returnInsertIdItemProject = MutableLiveData<Long>()

fun insertProject(){
    var projectEntity = ProjectEntity()
    projectEntity.name = et_item_project_title.value!!
    projectEntity.date = et_item_project_date.value!!
    projectEntity.location = et_item_project_location.value!!
    projectEntity.delete = 0

    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        _returnInsertIdItemProject.postValue(repository.insertProject(projectEntity))
    }
}
```

FRAGMENT

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel._returnInsertIdItemProject.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        newRowId = viewModel._returnInsertIdItemProject.value!!
    })
}

fun insertProject() {
    viewModel.insertProject()
    if (newRowId > 0){
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.item_project_save_message_ok, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_itemProjectFragment_to_listProjectFragment)

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "ID: $newRowId" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

El problema de esta aproximación es que el 'newRowId' dentro de "InsertProject()" siempre es -1, es decir, la asignación dentro del observe no se puede acceder fuera de él. Entiendo que ese es el problema. Cómo podría hacer para que me devuelva el ID insertado, pregunte por ese valor, muestre un mensaje y me lleve a otro fragment??
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La pregunta no es muy clara pero creo que lo que intentas hacer es que `viewModel.insertProject()` retorne el resultado de `repository.insertProject()`. De ser así has lo siguiente:

1. define en `repository.insertProject` el contexto en el cual debe ejecutarse. Es una mala práctica delegarle esa responsabilidad al caller

   ```
   class Repository {
       suspend fun insertProject(project: ProjectEntity) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. en el viewModel, elimina el liveData `_returnInsertIdItemProject` y convierte `insertProject` en una suspend function

   ```
   suspend fun insertProject(): Long {
       val projectEntity = ProjectEntity().apply {
           name = et_item_project_title.value!!
           date = et_item_project_date.value!!
           location = et_item_project_location.value!!
           delete = 0
       }
       return repository.insertProject(projectEntity)
   }
   ```
3. ahora en el fragment ya no necesitas un observer entonces puedes eliminar `onActivityCreated` completamente. De todas formas ese método está deprecado así que no deberias haber estado usandolo. Finalmente en `insertProject` crea una coroutine usando `lifecycleScope.launch`

   ```
   fun insertProject() = lifecycleScope.launch {
       val newRowId = viewModel.insertProject()
       if (newRowId > 0) {
           Toast
               .makeText(context, R.string.item_project_save_message_ok, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
               .show()
           findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_itemProjectFragment_to_listProjectFragment)
       } else Toast
           .makeText(context, "ID: $newRowId", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
           .show()
   }
   ```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! tu respuesta me sirvió. Consulto si esta forma es la mejor para hacer un insert y mostrar un mensaje y navegar a otro fragment o debería buscar otra forma de hacerlo? Gracias!

Comment: obviamente hay otras alternativas pero ninguna es "la mejor". No veo ningún problema con esta, usala si te sirve y te resulta cómoda. Si te sirvió la respuesta debes marcarla como aceptada y un voto positivo tambíen se agradece.

Comment: Perfecto! muchas gracias por la ayuda! Ya la marco como aceptada y voto positivo.